# Django: Is it possible to open a transaction, ask a user for confirmation, then commit the transaction if confirmed or roll back

Tags: django, transactions, commit, rollback

I've read the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/

But what's not clear to me, is whether a transaction can span HTTP requests.

The idea is simple enough:

1. user submits a form
2. backend then

   1. opens a transaction
   2. saves the data
   3. presents user with a confirmation form
   4. user then confirms or cancels
3. backend then commits on confirmation or rolls back on cancel

The main issue being that the transaction is opened on on HTTP request, then a user response is waited for (if never received I imagine on a time out we'd roll back) and when it comes on a second HTTP request, the transaction is committed.

I see nothing covering such a use case in the docs and have found nothing on-line. Yet it would strike me as a fairly ordinary use case. It arises primarily because the submission is complicated, involving many models and relations, and the easiest (almost only sensible or tenable) way to examine the submissions impact is to save all those and then study the impact. That works brilliantly as it happens, but I've thus far been force to make a commit or roll back decision in the one request, when processing the form. I'd like now to throw my analysis back at the user and ask for an OK, before I commit!

It strikes me to do this, the second request needs to know which transaction the confirmation relates to, and to determine if that transaction is open and then commit it or roll it back. This adds a whole tier of transaction identification that I can't see in the Django docs.

**Database support:**

Interesting Postgresql can support this as long as the whole transaction belongs to a single session (database connection), as I suspect other databases do. So this means it can only work if the save is performed by a persistent daemon that can start a transaction and stay running until the transaction is confirmed and committed or rolled back.

Which raises the ancillary question, of whether Django provides such a facility. I suspect not alas. I suspect that persistent workers are the domain of either uWsgi and/or Celery. And the persistent daemon that holds the database connection pending the confirmation request, is I suspect called a transaction manager.

And so this question really becomes in terser language: Is there an easy/canonical way of implementing a transaction manager for Django.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any library that will straightforwardly do like what you said. Although How I would go about this problem is after form submission I will store the variables in request session and perform necessay DB validation checks, upon which user can confirm and the transaction can execute.
In Django you can perform atomic transactions using transaction library

```
from django.db import transaction
```

Which allows you to either use 
`@transaction.atomic` decorator or a context function in view

```
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        do_more_stuff()
```

You can read more about it in Django docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Alas you touch on the central problem I'm exploring. That is, Django provides an ORM which allows a rich object oriented view of persistent (living in a database) objects. The very benefit of the ORM is that we can do a lot of interesting work with the objects easily and quickly. The reason for doing it in a transaction is to do it provisionally, so that the impact can be assessed and rollback is an option. In short there is a lot of work that can be done in the ORM that cannot be done from the form submission alone.

Comment: Oh and oddly you recommend reading a document that I said, in the question I'd read.  Also i know how to implement transactions that completed in one HTTP request. The challenge is to have one span HTTP requests so you can get user input on whether to commit or roll back. And I suspect this needs a transaction manager running as a daemon that can hold the database connection open during the interaction and Celery may be the most popular and accessible way of doing that though I can't find yet a canonical method of communicating with a running Celery task that holds such a transaction open.